# Having some troubles with mathematical logic.

Tags: logic

We will define $L_{pc} = \{P_{A} : A \ is \ an \ elementary \ formula \  in \ L \}$

An elementary formula is an atomic formula or a formula of the type $\exists xB$ for some formula B.

This means, for every elementary formula A in the language L, we define an atomic sentence $P_{A}$. Now we will define a function $\phi$ from formulas to sentences in the next manner:

if A is elementary, then $\phi (A) = P_{A}$

if $ A = \neg B$ then $\phi (A) = \neg \phi (B) $

if $ A = B \lor C$ then $\phi (A) = \phi (B) \lor \phi (C) $

if $ A = (\exists xB \lor x \approx x) \lor \neg D $ then $\phi (A) = (P_{\exists xB} \lor P_{x \approx x} \lor \neg \phi (D)) $

Now this is the definition of the language $ L_{pc}$.

Now I need to translate the following formula, in the language $L = (+, \lt, 0)$

$\forall x (x+y \lt 0 \lor x \lt y) $

to the language $L_{pc}$.

To be honest I haven't fully understood how is this suppose to be translated, it might be too intuitive and that might be the reason I can't really put my finger on it.

Any help that could get me going and get me to the point where I understand how to translate formulas like that, would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hm.. What do you mean?

Comment: Probably you have to review the definitions of *atomic sentence* and *elementary formula*...

Comment: Ok, and then? I'm sorry but if you could just be more specific ..

Comment: Or perhaps just tell me what's wrong with my question

Comment: What is an elementary formula?? Is it anything like an atomic formula?

Comment: Oh, I got what you mean. Just know that till now, when you stated I don't accept answers, I didn't know that it is a possible thing. And I went on to accept many answers of previous asked questions. In addition, I do vote to helpful answers, I also write a comment to show my thanks. To you as well on the latest post.. so I'm having a difficulty understanding why you just stated that.

Comment: @bof I've edited the post with the meaning of an elementary formula

Comment: What about $\forall$ and $\land$ ? Are they defined as abbreviations ? Please, specify...

Comment: Case 1: $\phi(∀x(x+y<0∨x<y))$ is undefined, because the mapping $\phi$ is not defined for the $\forall$ case.

Comment: Case 2: $\forall$ is an abbreviation of $\lnot \exists \lnot$; in this case : $ϕ(∀x(x+y<0∨x<y))= ϕ(¬∃x¬(x+y<0∨x<y))= \lnot \phi(∃x¬(x+y<0∨x<y))= \lnot  ∃x¬(x+y<0∨x<y)$ because $∃x¬(x+y<0∨x<y)$ is *elementary*.

Comment: Case 2 is the correct case. Thank you very much!